# Plotly ticktext position

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

As a plotly-3Dscatter
I find none parameter for moving ticktext position
Is there anyway to set ticktext keep outside the plot(or figure?)
(the plot below contain ticktext overlap the drawing area)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvw0d.png)

Comment: there is not my friend. you can draw an invisible point outside and plot the text on it.  Or you can use hover option

Comment: have you tried this? https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#3d-annotations